# Webform does not allow create new contact if contact not in select list

Tags: webform-civicrm

Webform - CiviCRM integration.    Form with 2 civi contacts - participant (individual) and program (organization)

I have a dropdown list in the webform which shows list of program organizations that can be selected.  The prompt for + create new + shows but does not allow any data entry of a new contact.

Any suggestions for how this can be enabled?

Answer (score 2):

solved my own problem.   Looks like the +create+ new does not do in-place entry but is used in conjunction with the program field which is either  populated with the select list option or can be used to enter/create a new contact (program)